# Resize and reposition watermark bitmap in Android

Tags: android

I'm using the following method to add a watermark logo on top of an existing bitmap:

```
private Bitmap addWaterMark(Bitmap src) {
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

        Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.menu_logo);
        canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark, 0, 0, null);

        return result;
    }
```

How can I modify the above code to position the watermark in the bottom right of the bitmap, and to also make its width 33% of the bitmap, while maintaining its aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2):

Ended up getting it to work how I wanted like this:

```
private Bitmap addWaterMark(Bitmap src) {
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

        int watermarkPadding = 50;
        Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.menu_logo);
        int newWatermarkWidth = w / 3;
        int newWatermarkHeight = (waterMark.getHeight() * newWatermarkWidth) / waterMark.getWidth();
        Bitmap newWatermark = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(waterMark, newWatermarkWidth, newWatermarkHeight, true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(newWatermark, w - newWatermarkWidth - watermarkPadding, h - newWatermarkHeight - watermarkPadding, null);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
private Bitmap addWaterMark(Bitmap src) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);


    float scale = 0.33f;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    matrix.postTranslate(w - w * scale, h - h * scale);

    Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.menu_logo);
    canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark, matrix, null);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://duanniston.github.io/watermark/), you can draw you watermark in XML (view) and convert to Bitmap and add on your original.

```
 private Bitmap generateWaterMark(Bitmap src) {

    //src is your original image
    WaterMark waterMark = new WaterMark(mContext);
    //return the your original image with watermark added
    return waterMark.getImageWaterMarkFromView(src, R.layout.watermark_all);
}
```